# What is the value of $\text{arctanh}(\sqrt{z})-\text{arctanh}(1/\sqrt{z})$ if $z$ is a complex number

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, trigonometry

I would like to know that is the value of:
$$\text{arctanh}(\sqrt{z})-\text{arctanh}(1/\sqrt{z}),$$
depending on $z\in\mathbb{C}$. I see in Mathematica that [in this post](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Arctanh%5BSqrt%5Bz%5D%5D-Arctanh%5B1%2FSqrt%5Bz%5D%5D&lang=es), i.e., if $-\infty<z<1$, then the value is $i\pi/2$ and if $z>1$ then the value is $-i\pi/2$. Note that I am considering the principal argument, that is, $\arg(z)\in(-\pi,\pi]$.

What happen if we consider an arbitrary $z$?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: I made edits to your post. Let me know if I made a mistake.

Comment: @DavisJohnson I fear you did make a mistake: you have changed the question from $\mathrm{arctanh}$ to $\arg \tanh$, which I don't think (from the rest of his post) is what OP meant.

Comment: @mcd I believe that was the users mistake. I will make changes anyways.

Comment: @ivan Let me know if I made any errors with my edits.

Comment: I believe $$\tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{z}\right)-\tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}\right)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{ \pi i}{2} & \Im(z)>0 \\
 -\frac{\pi i}{2} & \Im(z)<0 \\
\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: @StevenClark It seems true; and in the strictly real case, when $|z|<1$ is /2, it can be seen using the logarithm representation; however, I do not know how to do the complex case with $\Im(z)\neq 0$. Do you know it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result depends on a choice of definition to make the multivalued relations  $\mathrm{artanh}\, z$ and $\sqrt z$ into functions for (most) complex arguments. A sensible definition is to use the logarithm form $\mathrm{artanh}\, z \equiv \frac{1}{2}\ln\Big(\dfrac{1+z}{1-z}\Big)$ which is well defined except for branch cuts on the real axis excluding $(-\infty,-1]$ and $[1, \infty)$.

Then let $z= r^2 e^{2i\theta}$, with $r\ge0$ and $-\frac{\pi}{2}<\theta \le\frac{\pi}{2}$ and define $\sqrt{z} \equiv r e^{i\theta}$. Now put $f(z)\equiv \mathrm{artanh}\, \sqrt{z} - \mathrm{artanh}\, \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{z}} $. Then $$f(z)=\tfrac{1}{2}\ln\Big(\dfrac{1-r^2+2i\sin\theta}{1+r^2-2r\cos\theta}\Big)-\tfrac{1}{2}\ln\Big(\dfrac{r^2-1-2i\sin\theta}{1+r^2-2r\cos\theta}\Big).$$ The denominator in each logarithm is real and positive, and the magnitudes of the arguments of the two logarithms are equal, so the value of $f(z)$ is determined by the imaginary parts of the logarithms:$$f(z)=\tfrac{1}{2}i\arg (w)-\tfrac{1}{2}i\arg(-w),$$ where $w=1-r^2+2i\sin\theta$. This gives $\frac{1}{2}i\pi$ if $\theta>0$  and $-\frac{1}{2}i\pi$ if $\theta<0$ (noting the quadrants in which $w$ and $-w$ appear) as required.